# Can gyroscope hang, stop working, return zeros?

Tags: ios, ipad, air, gyroscope, adobe-native-extensions

Testing on iPad 4, happened also on iPad mini. AIR application uses native extension to retrieve data from gyroscope. Sometimes, seems like after a while of not using the iPad, everything works fine, but the gyroscope returns zeros or just doesn't fire the event at all (not sure which one). It's hard to say because I haven't put logs to check it untill now and now I have to wait for the event to occur. That is why I need to ask if such an event can actually happen? The devices are 100% working.

Comment: check your code. If gyroscope hangs phone will reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It can look like it's hang when you use CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical, because the device looks for its location and only after finding it it will start to dispatch sensor events.